# C# xaml datagrid binding 'list of a value'

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, binding

Hi
I use wpf and mvvm
so the binding to my viewmodel is ok!

I have a class Question which has the property `IEnumerable<Variation> Variations`
Variation has the property `IEnumerable<<keyValuePair<QuestionParameter,string>>> QuestionParameters`
QuestionParameter has the property Name.

So let's say I have a datagrid with the Itemssource= SelectedQuestion.Variations

Now let's say I want this grid: qp = questionparamater en var = variation

```
Name questionpar1  | Name QuestionPar2  | Name QuestionPar3  | ...
string qp1 of var1 | string qp2 of var1 | string qp3 of var1 | ...
string qp1 of var2 | string qp2 of var2 | string qp3 of var2 | ...
...
```

how do I do this?

Comment: ok, done it.. Now Can someone solve my question please

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way would be to create a flat collection with the structure you want. if  QuestionParameters vary in ".Count"/are dynamic then its even harder :) i use a flat datatable for this tasks in my project, bause i can easily create columns dynamic.

i would say if you wanna use a datagrid you should create a flat collection.

i you want to use your dynamic collection you can use itemsscontrol datatemplates to create the output you want. the problem i see with this, is that you maybe have to sync the QuestionParameter for each item in Variations.

if QuestionParameter are not dynamic (e.g. fixed number: q1, q2,q3, q4), you can use a datagrid and a converter with convertparamter (QuestionParameter ) for displaying your results.